# how to use custom fonts in Umbraco 4

Tags: asp.net, css, fonts, umbraco

I have bunch of custom fonts and I put them in

```
/root/css/fonts/
```

I even tried to put here

```
Umbraco/config/fonts
```

either way doesn't work... it's not picking up my fonts... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you want to use these fonts? In umbraco's content editing html editor ?

Comment: exactly Jags... that's my primary objective but I should be able to use it throughout my webpage too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the fonts anywhere you want, as long as the CSS that uses them points to (and has access to) them.

Comment: Hi E.J... I have all my css working...and they work fine on my local machine... but on the webbrowser it doesn't show those fonts

Answer (score 0):

you should add MINE TYPE to you IIS, that will be help